# Manipulating css using attr() and data tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div class like so:

```
<div class="website-wrapper" data-content="63%"></div>
```

I have javascript that changes the `data-content`:

```
$(this).children().closest('.website-wrapper').attr('data-content', (imageHeight/imageWidth*100)+"%");
```

And I have my css declaration like this:

```
.website-wrapper:after { padding-top: attr(data-content); display: block; content: ''; }
```

---

For some reason, I can't get the `padding-top` to work correctly. Is there something I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the relation between the css and that data attribute??

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy On click I grab an image. I then determine it's real width and height and divide the 2. I want to make that value the padding-top so that I can make `.website-wrapper` have the right ratio for the image responsively.

Comment: The first thing to check is: Is the attribute getting updated with the value you expect?

Comment: Maybe imageHeight or imageWidth return undefined? Did you check this?

Comment: _The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties **other than content is experimental.**_ [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Comment: Hmm @zgood thanks for that. Can anyone think of a way to affect an `:after` property. The `data-content` is being updated with what I expect.

Comment: @bryan are you using the `padding-top` to maintain a certain aspect ratio as outlined [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/)?

Comment: @zgood yup! but all my images have unconventional aspect ratio's which is the main reason for needing to divide the height/weight.

Comment: @bryan just curious, are you rendering out the images as `<img />` tags or are the images set as `background-images`?

Comment: @zgood background-images

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know `attr` works only with `content` property currently, so you can manipulate only it. You can see browser compatibility here and more detail info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

```css
.website-wrapper:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<div class="website-wrapper" data-content="Hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include a wrapping div you could use that to set your `padding-top` to maintain you aspect ratio. Just set that wrapping div to `position: relative;` and the inner div with the `background-image` can be set to `position: absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` in order to take up the full space of the containing div which is creating the aspect ratio.

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="website-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer{
  position:relative;
}

.website-wrapper{
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/800x450');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  border:1px solid red;
}
```

JS

```
$(this).children().closest('.outer').css('padding-top', (imageHeight/imageWidth*100)+"%");
```

[See this fiddle for a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/67c9env6/)